# Rails scope without using SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to set up a scoped query where I can find customers that have paid (or partially paid) an invoice.

However, the value I want to use in the scope isn't actually in the database, it's a method.

For example:

Bidder.rb

```
class Bidder < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  scope :unpaid, where(payment_status: 'unpaid')

  ...

  def payment_status
    "paid" if whatever
    "partial" if whatever
    "unpaid" if whatever
  end
  ...
end
```

When I try to use:

```
@auction.bidders.unpaid
```

I see this:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: bidders.payment_status: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "bidders"  WHERE "bidders"."auction_id" = 7 AND "bidders"."payment_status" = 'unpaid'
```

What do I need to change to get something like this to work? Should I even be using scopes?

Also, how can I change that scope to search for both 'unpaid' and 'partial' values?

Thanks

Comment: Give more details of model. Here `payment_status` is an internal instance method, not an attribute which SQL can organize while calling out a scope.

Comment: That's why I'm asking if I should be using `scope` at all. The way I want to narrow down my search is by filtering from non db data.

Answer (score 1):

You could use scope like this:

```
scope :unpaid, all.select{ |bidder| bidder.payment_status == 'unpaid' }
```

This way you will have an array of unpaid bidders, but if you want to chain methods you have to convert that array to a relation like this:

```
scope :unpaid, where(id: all.select{ |bidder| bidder.payment_status == 'unpaid' }.map(&:id))
```

See that you are hitting database eagerly, you maybe want to have payment_status as a computed value for performance.

Comment: Hmm. I get `undefined method 'payment_status' for #<Bidder:0x007f85dcd885d8>` when using either of those.

Comment: what does `Bidder.first.payment_status` or `Bidder.new.payment_status` output?

Comment: Returns the results as expected. `"paid"` and `"n/a"` respectively.

Comment: and `p Bidder.first` and `p Bidder.new`?

Comment: `payment_status` *isn't* there

Comment: should appear `#<Bidder:0x007f8...`

Comment: `#<Bidder:0x007fca16ad8620> { :id => 9, :auction_id => 7, :customer_id => 2, :bidder_number => 1, :custom_buyer_premium_rate => nil, :tax_exempt => nil, :created_at => Mon, 13 May 2013 13:07:34 EDT -04:00, :updated_at => Mon, 13 May 2013 13:07:34 EDT -04:00, :use_custom_buyer_premium_rate => false, :lots_count => 1, :amount_paid => 0.0 }`